# cannot connect phpPgAdmin on ec2 instance to RDS Pgsql

Tags: postgresql, amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-rds, phppgadmin

I am trying to connect my AWS RDS postgres database to my remotely accessible phpPgAdmin which is running on an ec2 instance. I am able to access the phpPhAdmin page, and have edited the  config.inc.php file in the phpPgAdmin folder so that it includes the endpoint of the RDS server.

This is the relevant portion of the config.inc.php.

```
    /**
     * Central phpPgAdmin configuration.  As a user you may modify the
     * settings here for your particular configuration.
     *
     * $Id: config.inc.php-dist,v 1.55 2008/02/18 21:10:31 xzilla Exp $
     */

    // An example server.  Create as many of these as you wish,
    // indexed from zero upwards.

    // Display name for the server on the login screen
    $conf['servers'][0]['desc'] = 'Visionmap';

    // Hostname or IP address for server.  Use '' for UNIX domain socket.
    // use 'localhost' for TCP/IP connection on this computer
    $conf['servers'][0]['host'] = '*myRDSendpoint*';

    // Database port on server (5432 is the PostgreSQL default)
    $conf['servers'][0]['port'] = 5432;
```

The problem is that I when I try to login to the server it takes forever and then says login failed. I have connected to the RDS server with pgAdminIII with the same username and password with no issues. I also have restarted the httpd several times. [phpPgAdmin timed out](https://i.stack.imgur.com/uqynO.jpg)

Answer (score 0):

This thread on Serverfault.com provides the answer.

https://serverfault.com/questions/402127/cant-login-to-phppgadmin

I wasn't enabling TCP inbound traffic from the EC2's public ip address.